# ERC777 Deployment with Transaction Reverted Error

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin

I'm working to deploy an ERC777 token using hardhat, ethers in typescript. My deployment script is as follows

```js
import { MarketSvc, ProductSvc } from '../libs/deployment-service/src';
import hre from 'hardhat';
async function main() {
    const marketAddress = await MarketSvc.deployContract(contractType);
    const productAddress =  await ProductSvc.deployContract(contractType, marketAddress);
}
```

my execution function looks like this

```js
async deployContract(
    contractType: ContractType,
    ...args: any[]
): Promise<string> {
const contractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory(contractType);
    const contract =
  args === undefined
            ? await contractFactory.deploy()
            : await contractFactory.deploy(...args);
    await contract.deployed();
    console.log(contractType + ' Contract deployed to:', contract.address);
    return contract.address;
}
```

The first deployment succeeds. The second deployment fails with and error of

```
MarketContract Contract deployed to: 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512
ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account       
at HttpProvider.request (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:49:19)
at GanacheGasMultiplierProvider.request (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\gas-providers.ts:312:34)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

In the ERC777 contract it is failing in the method below (@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC777\ERC777.sol:75)

```
  /**
 * @dev `defaultOperators` may be an empty array.
 */
constructor(
    string memory name_,
    string memory symbol_,
    address[] memory defaultOperators_
) {
    _name = name_;
    _symbol = symbol_;

    _defaultOperatorsArray = defaultOperators_;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < defaultOperators_.length; i++) {
        _defaultOperators[defaultOperators_[i]] = true;
    }

    console.log("added operators");

    // register interfaces - It is failing here
    _ERC1820_REGISTRY.setInterfaceImplementer(address(this), keccak256("ERC777Token"), address(this));
    console.log("registered ERC777");
    _ERC1820_REGISTRY.setInterfaceImplementer(address(this), keccak256("ERC20Token"), address(this));
}
```

the constructor to my contract is this

```
    constructor(address defaultOperator)
    ERC777("SOMEtoken", "TKN", _defaultOps(defaultOperator)) {
        console.log(defaultOperator);
        _mint(_msgSender(), 1000000, "Initial Mint", "defaultOps");
}
```

my solidity log is

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
  at GParticle.constructor (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol:75)       
  at EthModule._estimateGasAction (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:425:7)
  at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:138:22)
  at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:115:18)
  at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:188:20)
  at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:167:17)
  at Server.JsonRpcHandler.handleHttp (C:\src\trae\gbc\exchange\exchange_ui\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:52:21)
```

the operator address I'm giving it, is defiantly deployed and is a contract. but so I'm a bit baffled about what could possibly be happening in the 777 contract specifically.  I have a ERC20 and 1155 that deploy perfectly...

If anyone has any insight, all information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue is that if you're working on a localnet, like hardhat... you will have to deploy your own ERC1820_REGISTRY, because it does not exist.

openzepplin has some utilites you can use to enable this pretty simply..

```
const { singletons } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers/configure')

async function main() {
    const signers = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    const address = signers[0].address;
    const erc1820 = await singletons.ERC1820Registry(address);

    ... deploy your ERC777
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a full deployment of ERC1820 & ERC777,
my code checks if it's not deployed, deploys it, and then deploys the ERC777 and registers the recipient,
It's implemented with hardhat and I put the guide in the readme.md

This is my repo :

https://github.com/EhsanParsania/ERC777